# ng-repeat="(key, value)" cannot use value of {{key}} as part of global scope for another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,x) in selectedPoll.questions">
    <p>{{x}}</p>
    <p>{{key}}</p>
    <canvas chart-directive data="arrayResult.{{key}}" id="{{ $index }}">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

When i use {{key}} in global scope for chart-directive, {{ $index}} is not accessible, although when i delete {{key}} and leave just arrayResult, ng-repeat is working.

Explanation: i use id {{ $index }} which is searched by chart-directive for each x in ng-repeat, thanks to this i can create as many chart-directives as i need.

Then in order to everything work properly i have to pass proper dataset, each dataset for chart-directive has the same ending as {{ key }} of x in ng-repeat so for example:

```
 data="arrayResult.q1 "
```

to make it dynamic i would like to switch it to:

```
 data="arrayResult.{{ key }}
```

but when i add {{ key }} ng-repeat stop with one result which as i assume is happening because it cannot read id value of {{ $index }}

It is the first time i use key and $index with ng-repeat, and it is first time when i repeat custom directive, so i don't know if the problem is with repeating custom directives or rather wrong use of {{ key }} value.

Just when i added the question some solution came to my head, it could be that it is happening because in my custom directive my scope.data looks like this

```
   scope: {
                data:'='
            },
```

So If I am right if somebody can tell me if it is possible and if it is how to make scope data open for expression like this "arrayResult.{{ key }}  ??

Comment: try `data="{{ 'arrayResult.'+ key }}` it should work

Comment: `data="arrayResult[key]"` as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `@` is only relevant if your chart data are strings.

You can keep the `=` of your directive, but you need to change:

```
data="arrayResult.{{key}}"
```

into this:

```
data="arrayResult[key]"
```

The curcly brackets will only work with a `@` scoping indeed, but you would get the string `"arrayResult.q1"` instead of the actual value of what is in arrayResult.q1, so `=` is the way to go.

See a snippet simulating it below:

```js
angular.module("test", []).controller("test", function($scope) {

  $scope.questions = {q1: "do you like apples?", q2: "do you like bananas?"};
  
  $scope.arrayResult = {q1: true, q2: false};

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
  <div ng-repeat="(key,x) in questions">
      <p>question: {{x}}</p>
      <p>key: {{key}}</p>
      <div>result: {{arrayResult[key]}}</div>
      </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right i cannot use @ because it will give me a string, but when i tried your solution  data= "arrayResult[key]"  in console it gave me just arrayResult[key], [ key ] is not changed into q1 q2 q3

Comment: Can you log what is in `$scope.data` in your directive link/controller? I have edited my answer with a snippet where you can see that `arrayResult[key]` is the right format, but I don't have enough information to understand what is wrong in your code.

Comment: I think i understand know, there is some problems with watch which keep eye on global scope data, but your solution arrayResult[key] works